# javascript: Use RegEx to allow letters, numbers, and spaces (with at least one letter and number)

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to build a regular expression which **allows** following cases:

- M1 1AA
- B33 8TH
- CR2 6XH
- DN55 1PT
- W1A 1HQ
- EC1A 1BB

and **should not allow**, only a single letter or a single number. E.g:

- A
- 2
- AA AAA
- 22 343

Also how do i call this in javascript. I am currently using the RegEx

`^[A-Z0-9 ]*[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9 ]*$`

Which validates all the above cases includin a single letter or single number.

Please help me how to use a javascript to be called on a textbox change n validate using above regular expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.  One way to solve this problem would be

```
^[A-Z0-9 ]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9 ]*\d[A-Z0-9 ]*$|^[A-Z0-9 ]*\d[A-Z0-9 ]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9 ]*$
```

which allows arbitrary letter, number, or space (`[A-Z0-9 ]*`) before, after, and between the letter and number, and allows either the letter to come first or the number to come first.

However, there's another way to solve this.  You could use two regular expressions.  First, check against the regular expression

```
^[A-Z0-9 ]*$
```

which checks that you have only letters, numbers, and spaces.  Then, check against the regular expression

```
[A-Z][A-Z0-9 ]*\d|\d[A-Z0-9 ]*[A-Z]
```

which checks for at least one letter (`[A-Z]`) and one number (`\d`), with both orders allowed.  Note that this pattern doesn't include the hat and dollar sign, so the letter and number can occur anywhere in the string.

The two-regular-expression approach has the benefit of being easier to read and modify later.

Comment: This allows only letters as well E.g AA AAA and 22 232. I want atleast one letter and one number. E.g A2, AA2, 22A

Comment: @Ishan I've edited the regular expression in my answer to check for at least one letter and at least one number.

Comment: The two-patterns approach is broken in cases where the input begins and ends with a letter with a number between (e.g., A1A or 1A1) which seem to be valid based on the spec.

Comment: I'm on my phone so I can't test right now, but something like [A-Z][A-Z0-9 ]*[0-9][A-Z]*|[0-9][A-Z0-9 ]*[A-Z][0-9]* would seem to work around that (and if you put ^ at the start and $ at the end of each valid pattern you shouldn't need two patterns; if you do want two patterns, you could split on the pipe and test for letter-then-number and number-then-letter separately)