# To check if a string is alphanumeric in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if a string is *strictly alphanumeric* in JavaScript. I have tried this:

```
var Exp = /^[0-9a-z]+$/;
if(!pwd.match(Exp))
    alert("ERROR")
```

But the problem with this is it passes the input sting if it contains all alphabet or all numeric. I want the function to pass if it contains both *characters* and *numbers*.

Comment: If we're being picky "alphanumeric" means either alpha and/or numeric.. not just alpha AND numeric

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to accept atleast one alphabet one numeric char and one special Character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026283/regex-to-accept-atleast-one-alphabet-one-numeric-char-and-one-special-character) and [Use RegEx to allow letters, numbers, and spaces (with at least one letter and number)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9765339/218196).

Comment: Do you mean that the string has to contain at least one character and at least one number?

Comment: hey but i needed that for password validation and i need both alpha and numeric, so can u suggest somethin.

Comment: Yes exactly, Stain I want the string to contain alteast one letter and a character in the string

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that there are way more characters that can be considered a letter, so part of an alphanumeric string then just `a-zA-Z`:
check out [Unicode Property Escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) for using something like `/\p{Letter}/u` as a regular expression instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/((^[0-9]+[a-z]+)|(^[a-z]+[0-9]+))+[0-9a-z]+$/i
```

Which allows only alphanumeric.

It doesn't allow:

- Only alpha
- Only numbers

Refer to **[a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/JCRcQ/2/)**.

### An alternative:

The below regex allows:

```
/^([0-9]|[a-z])+([0-9a-z]+)$/i
```

- Alphanumeric
- Only alpha
- Only numbers

Answer (score 8):

[Felix Kling's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299036/to-check-if-a-string-is-alphanumeric-in-javascript/16299241#16299241) is the best single-regex solution in my opinion, but I would consider doing it with three patterns. This allows you to return useful error messages:

```
if(pwd.match(/[^0-9a-z]/i))
    alert("Only letters and digits allowed!");
else if(!pwd.match(/\d/))
    alert("At least one digit required!");
else if(!pwd.match(/[a-z]/i))
    alert("At least one letter required!");
else
    // process pwd
```

You should consider allowing non-alphanumeric characters for your passwords though - that would make them a lot safer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)[a-z\d]+$/i
   ^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^
    at least   at least
   one letter  one digit
```

---

FYI, restricting the allowed characters for a password reduce the entropy **a lot** (there are only 36 different characters now) and hence makes them much easier to crack. Don't do this restriction. Checking whether the string contains a certain type of character is fine though (well, there are some theories that this reduces entropy as well, but I don't have enough knowledge about that).

See also: [Regex to accept atleast one alphabet one numeric char and one special Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026283/regex-to-accept-atleast-one-alphabet-one-numeric-char-and-one-special-character)

Answer (score 4):

The right function is

```
function isAlphaNumeric(str) {
  return str.match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i) !== null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var pwd = 'somevalue';
if(pwd.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")){
   alert('aplanumeric');
}
else{
   alert('Not alphanumeric');
}
```

Comment: That doesnty works means? Can you show how you are cheking aplanumeric or not

Comment: It's not what the OP wants. They want to ensure that the string contains at least one digit and one letter.

Comment: @Felix Kling He want to check whether a string is alphanumeric or not and he mentioned it in the question

Comment: And he also said in the question: *"i want the function to pass if it contains both Characters and Numbers."* and in the comments *"I want the string to contain alteast one letter and a character in the string"*.

Answer (score 3):

I hate to be that guy, but I also hate all the answers I found here, so here's mine.

```
function isalnum(data) {
  return !/\W|_/.exec(data)
}
```

What's going on here?

- `\w` is the "word" class.

  - it's a shortcut to match alphanumerics and the underscore (`_`)
  - it's meant to be used to match identifiers in formal languages
  - You could write it `[A-za-z0-9_]`
- `\W` it's the "negated" form of the "word" class.

  - It's the opposite of "\w".
  - You could also write it `[^A-za-z0-9_]`

If you didn't bother about accepting an underscore and were simply sanitizing some inputs, you could just have used:

```
!/\W/.exec(data)
```

or even, the more straighforward:

```
/^\w*$/.exec(data)
```

And here I'm using RegExp.exec() but you could as well prefer using String.match() and in that case you would write

```
!data.match(/\W|_/)
```

And why, **YES**, I *do* like regexps.

Answer (score 2):

Regex:

`/^[a-z0-9]+$/i`

Faster than regex:

```js
function isAlphaNumeric(str) {
  var code, i, len;

  for (i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
    code = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if (!(code > 47 && code < 58) && // numeric (0-9)
        !(code > 64 && code < 91) && // upper alpha (A-Z)
        !(code > 96 && code < 123)) { // lower alpha (a-z)
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

String myString1 = "abcdefghijklmnop1";

```
    /**
     * To Check Alphanumeric myString1==ABCD is Working;myString1==123 is Working;myString1==ABCD123 is not Working
     */
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
```

The p1 will show false if you check whether it contains bothe alphabet and numeric so use Pattern p if you want to check whether it either contains alphabet or numeric you can use Pattern p1

```
    /**
     * To Check both Alpha and Numeric only myString1==ABCD123 is Working
     */

    Pattern p = Pattern
            .compile("[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*");

    boolean hasSpecialChar = p.matcher(myString1).find();

    if (hasSpecialChar) {

        System.out.println("Working");

    } else {

        System.out.println("not Working");

    }

                     /***************OR*******************/
```

char[] charArray = myString1.toCharArray();

```
    for (char ch : charArray) {

        if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {

        }
        if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {

            containsletter = true;
        }

        if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {

            containsdigits = true;

        }
     }
       if(containsletter&&containsdigits){

            System.out.println("Working");

       }
       else{

            System.out.println("not Working");

       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way to do this without regexes:

```
function stringIsStrictlyAlphaNumeric(string)
{
    //returns true for letters, digits or both
    var stringIsLooselyAlphanumeric = string => [...string].every(character => '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCEDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.includes(character));
    //returns true for digits only 
    var stringIsComposedOfDigitsOnly = string => [...string].every(character => '0123456789'.includes(character));  
    //returns true for letters only 
    var stringIsComposedOfLettersOnly = string => [...string].every(character => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCEDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.includes(character)); 
    //returns true for letters and digits only.
    return stringIsLooselyAlphanumeric(string) && !stringIsComposedOfDigitsOnly(string) && !stringIsComposedOfLettersOnly(string);  
}
```

Please use like so:

```
stringIsStrictlyAlphaNumeric('hello123'); //returns true
stringIsStrictlyAlphaNumeric('hello');    //returns false
stringIsStrictlyAlphaNumeric('123');      //returns false
stringIsStrictlyAlphaNumeric('');         //returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any number of characters (as opposed to accepted answer)

`/^[a-z0-9]*$/i`